# is it possible to remove only valid tags in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization

I'm crawling some news articles.
and I'm attempting to remove all tags inside the news title
using `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper.sanitize`

but if the title contains string like `<scoop> some news title`,
the word and <> are considered as a HTML tag and removed and the result is `some news title`.. it's not what i want.

is there any way to remove only valid tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by defining which tag. only the mentioned tags  are allowed, nothing else

```
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(table tr td) %>
```

Comment: I cannot expect which word will be inserted inside <>, and that word shouldn't be removed, so whitelist based approach cannot be used.